# ошибка 0x80131500 при отладке в студии

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

У меня появилась проблема со студией. Я установил [расширение](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=35471) для студии позволяющие создавать проекты для windows phone 8.0, но появилась проблема при попытке запуска или отладки приложения выдаёт ошибку `0x80131500`. Что делать?

```
1>------ Развертывание начато: проект: PhoneApp1, Конфигурация: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Развертывание F:\Документы\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PhoneApp1\PhoneApp1\Bin\Debug\PhoneApp1_Debug_AnyCPU.xap...Подключение к Emulator WVGA 512MB(RU)...
1>Не удалось выполнить развертывание приложения на устройстве.
1>0x80131500
========== Развертывание: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Os windows 8.1 enterprise

Comment: Версия Windows какая? это проблема именно с OS а не со студией

Comment: @Dmitry windows 8.1 enterprise

Comment: Какой сервис пак на студии установлен последним? данная проблема была на 8.1 превью, лечилась сервиспаком студии SP3

Comment: @Dmitry у меня стоит SP2, можно ссылочку на SP3?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2835600 Update - 3

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305 Update 4